# How to highlight specific row in a DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer. I am using a DetailsView now to dispaly some data from the database. I have the need to highlight certain two rows from the DetailsView. Both rows are VARCHAR data type.
**SO HOW TO DO THAT?**

Comment: Select multiple rows, or change the color of the background to indicate selection?

Answer (score 0):

Override the databound event and set the `e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;` or what ever color, if you have some logic to execute for finding the row that needs to be highlighted.

```
protected void detailsView_RowDataBound(object sender, 
GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(...)//some condition for selection of row to be higlighted
        {
           e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need a perticular row, say 4th row to be highlighted and that's fixed then you could directly like this

```
detailsViewGrid.Rows[3].Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

The only thing you need to keep in mind that this code would be written in only those events which would come after grid_rowdatabound event(Like pre-render)

Comment: Yes, what I want is just 4th row to be highlighted and that's fixed. So how to do that? I put it inside the detailsView_RowDataBound(object sender, 
GridViewRowEventArgs e)
but it does not work. It gave the following error: The name: 'detailsView' does not exist is the current context

Comment: Actually, I think there is no RowDataBound for the detailsview.